# Idle Time for Heap Sort

Tags: algorithm

Hi there is this question in an Algorithm's textbook which I am lost and don't even understand the question. Here is the question:

> Idle time. Suppose that a parallel machine processes N jobs. Write a program that, given the list of job start and finish times, finds the largest interval where the machine is idle and the largest interval where the machine is not idle.

Would someone be able to explain the question first and maybe give me pseudo code which would be super useful?

Comment: I'm removing the sorting and heapsort tags from this problem, since the question doesn't directly involve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a machine that can execute multiple jobs at the same times. When the machine is not processing any jobs at all, it is idle. You are given a list of start and stop times of all the jobs and asked when the machine was idle, so when no jobs were running.

So given this schedule:

- Job 1: Starts at 00:00 and ends at 10:00
- Job 2: Starts at 11:00 and ends at 12:00
- Job 3: Starts at 05:00 and ends at 06:00

The machine was idle between 10:00 and 11:00, this is the only and largest interval.

If the jobs repeat every day there is another interval from 12:00 to 00:00, but to keep the example simple you can assume these jobs only run once.

Pseudo code:

```
busy = []
for each Job
    find intervals in busy that overlap with job
    if no overlapping intervals are found
        add job interval to busy
    else
       remove overlapping intervals from busy  
       merge overlapping intervals with job interval
       add new interval to busy


find longest busy interval
create non-busy intervals from busy intervals
find longest non-busy interval
```

Comment: Is't the largest interval where the machine is idle between 12:00 and 5:00

Comment: Between 12:00 and 00:00. If you assume a cyclical day which is not unreasonable in this context but does make the algorithm a bit more complex then what you might want to start with.

Comment: As @NavleenSingh points out, either your data or your answer is incorrect.  Also, any example data should include overlap as that is implicitly part of the problem.  Also, your pseudocode is confusing at best, and at worse may be unimplementable or just logically incorrect.  It's impossible to tell as you've hand-waved away the important parts as abstractions.

Comment: OK, I see, you've got a 12-hour period/day.  A little confusing, but still makes sense once you know that.  The pseudocode is still a problem though.

Comment: I understand it but if I am still confused I will ask thank you!!

Comment: @RBarryYoung that is the point of the pseudo code. Actual code or a mathematical proof would be too involved. Feel free to write an example though.

Answer (score 2):

Question does not specifies if start and finish times given in pairs or separately. There is a simple algorithm for less simple case, when they are given separately, here. 
So we have all times in a single list but keep information if it start job time or finish job time.

for example:

```
13:00 start    
15:00 finish
8:30  start
10:00 finish
9:00  start    
12:00 finish
```

then sort this list by time:

```
8:30  start
9:00  start
10:00 finish
12:00 finish
13:00 start
15:00 finish
```

Than we need a counter of open jobs and we can process list, increment counter when start time is processed and decrement counter when finish time is processed; If counter is 0 it means that we enter idle state.

```
list.sort()
open_jobs = 0
state_changed_time = list[0].time; 
max_idle_interval = -1;
max_not_idle_interval = -1;
for each (element in list)
{
     if (element.type == start)
     {
          if(open_jobs == 0)
          {
               interval = element.time - state_changed_time;
               if (interval > max_idle_interval) max_idle_interval = interval;
               state_changed_time = element.time;
          }
          open_jobs +=1;
     }
     if (element.type == finish) 
     {
          open_jobs -= 1;
          if(open_jobs == 0)
          {
               interval = element.time - state_changed_time;
               if (interval > max_not_idle_interval) max_not_idle_interval = interval;
               state_changed_time = element.time;
          }
     }
}
```